# How to use append and extend in a function within a class without explicitly defining them in the same class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can i use append and extend in a class without defining them beforehand?

Example:

```
class Blabla():
    def append(self, x):
        self.row += [x]

    def extend(self, row):
        for i in row:
            self.row += [i]

    def combine(self, rows):
        row_1 = Blabla([])
        [...]
        row_1.append(self.row[i])
```

Comment: What is `row_1`, is it an object of the class type that these functions are presumably members in? Your example does not really offer the best context. Also your question asked if it is ok for the functions to not be defined beforehand, but your example appears to define them beforehand. Please clarify

Comment: @pooley1994 edited the code for a better understanding, yes row_1 is an object of the class. Also, yes my question is if I could do without them in my class?

Comment: can you inherit from `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Blabla` will not just have `append` and `extend` methods automatically somehow, so the short answer to your question of whether you can call them without having defined them, is no.

If your class had a member of type list (or of some other type with append and extend functions) then you could call append and extend on that member.

For instance if the `Blabla.row` member is a list type then doing the following would be legal...

```
...
row_1.row.append(...)
row_1.row.extend(...)
...
# or in one of the classes methods...
def foo(self, ...):
    self.row.append(...)
    self.row.extend(...)
```

Otherwise your class needs to define them first (either explicitly, by inheritance, or by some other means)